# AlarmManager calls the intent service ASAP rather than at the set time

Tags: android

I have a setExact alarm set up in my app and when it reaches that point, instead of activating the alarm at the specified time, it activates it ASAP!

My alarmmanager code

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
public void setUpAlarmManager(long time) {

    final Intent intentAlarm = new Intent(this, AlarmService.class);
    final PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 100, intentAlarm, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    final AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, pendingIntent);
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
        }
    }, 1000);
    Log.i(TAG, "setUpAlarmManager: " + time);
}
```

The handler is just to see if I can cancel the intent through my activity (which also doesn't appear to be working)

My AlarmService

```
public class AlarmService extends IntentService {

private static final String TAG = "Tag";

// private Ringtone ringtoneAlarm;

public AlarmService() {
    super("AlarmService");
//     ringtoneAlarm = null;
    Log.i(TAG, "AlarmService: ");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onHandleIntent: ");
    Uri alarmTone = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
    Ringtone ringtoneAlarm = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), alarmTone);
    ringtoneAlarm.play();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Log.i(TAG, "onDestroy: ");
    super.onDestroy();
//    ringtoneAlarm.stop();
}


}
```

How can I figure out why my AlarmManager is calling my intent right away instead of at the set time? Basically the intent service just plays an alarm when the alarm activates.

Also should I be using an intentservice for this or a broadcastreceiver?

Comment: It may be because the time you are passing to alarmManager is in the past.

Comment: @EvgenyMaltsev i set up a logi in my method for the time variable and its always above 0. it is a proper amount, like if my alarm is set for 32 seconds later its 32000 milliseconds

Comment: I believe that alarmTime is a date parsed to milliseconds. So if you wish to set an alarm for 10/02/2016 10:00:00, time = 1475391600000.

Comment: @EvgenyMaltsev even when i manually set the parameter to like 10000 milliseconds for 10 seconds it still loads automatically....

Comment: For `RTC_WAKEUP`, the time value is expressed in milliseconds since the Unix epoch. 10000 milliseconds is decades in the past. 10000 milliseconds from now is `System.currentTimeMillis()+10000`, in the RTC timebase.

Comment: @CommonsWare would it make sense to use ERT? I just tried using ERT and still called automatically. So would system.currentimemilli + time be the only solution? Because that seems like a hacky way to fix things

Comment: @alber: Sorry, but I do not know what "ERT" is. If you mean `ELAPSED_REALTIME`-based flags, you still need to add your value to a timebase. In that case, it is `SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()`, instead of `System.currentTimeMillis()` for `RTC`-based flags.

Comment: well i tried your method and it fixed my problem! thanks @CommonsWare this is exactly what i come to stack overflow for!

Answer (score 0):

To set the alarm to 32 seconds from now, you would do it like this:

```
private void setAlarmToFuthure(long time){
        Calendar cal_alarm = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal_alarm.add(Calendar.SECOND, (int)time); // Here you add the desired value to the current time (for example: 32 seconds)

        final Intent intentAlarm = new Intent(this, AlarmService.class);
        final PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 100, intentAlarm, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        final AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal_alarm.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
    }
```